# How to make my bot auto delete swear words and replacing them with like a warning?

Tags: discord, discord.js

```js
if (msg.content === 'SWEARWORD') {
    msg.reply('No swearing u nub >:) ');
}
```

How do I fix it and make it autodelete the swear words messages?

Answer (score 2):

You should use an array to store your words and check if the message's content contains them:

```js
const words = [ 'bread', 'apple', 'tea' ];
const forbiddenWord = words.some((word) => message.content.includes(word));
if (forbiddenWord ) {
    message.delete();
    message.channel.send('your message should not include : '+forbiddenWord);
}
```